# HTTPWebRequest won't INSERT null Value

Tags: c#, sql, httpwebrequest

I'm currently working on a Webform for some online business.
Having big problems with HTTPWebrequest. 
The function UpdateUserData() has some typical info for update in DataBase. Name, Email, itc.
The Problems come when user does not enter enything in [Birthday] cell and its DateTime (which is Nullable by the way) Value is Null.

Here is how I add Parameters:

```
    private void AddParam(string Key, object Value)
    {
        if (Value == null)
            Value = string.Empty;

        ParamStringBuilder.Append(string.Format("{0}={1}&", Key, HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Value.ToString())));
    }
```

And here is how I send the WebRequest:

```
    string _URL = URIBuilder(Action);
        HttpWebRequest httpWebRequest = HttpWebRequest.Create(_URL) as HttpWebRequest;
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Forwarded-For", HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress);// this is optional to log the original client ip address
        // add culture info of calling client
        if (SendBrowserCulture)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"] != null) // this is optional to access the api with the original culture settings
                httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Accept-Language", HttpContext.Current.Request.Headers["Accept-Language"].ToString());
        }
        using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            sw.Write(ParamStringBuilder);
        }
        // reset paramstringbuilder
        ParamStringBuilder.Clear();
        //Getting the Respose and reading the result.
        HttpWebResponse httpWebResponse = httpWebRequest.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
        APIResponse _Response = new APIResponse(httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream());
        return _Response;
```

I suspect that when SQL gets the URLencoded Command "Birthday=null" it reads it as

```
    INSERT 'null' INTO Table.Birthday
```

Which of course makes no sence to it, so it fills it with '0001-01-01'

I hope I was clear enough. Be glad to explain some more.

Thx for help in advance!

Comment: You need to change the code that handles the request to recognize some form of null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the server side code handling the processing of the WebRequest has the birthday date as a Nullable DateTime as well. You also need to make sure that the Birthday field in the database can accept NULL.

If this doesn't assist, please attach your server side processing code and your database schema.